# Should I remove python3.6 since I have python3.7

Tags: command-line, python, python3, pip

Ubuntu version is 18.10

First of all, I am new to linux(ubuntu) as well as python world.

From my understanding I currently have python2.7, python3.6 and also python3.7.

I have read that I should not uninstall python2 for some reasons.

But I wonder can I uninstall python 3.6 ?

It makes me confuse while trying to get used to using python within linux environment. I have problems while using pip, or pip3. I figured that pip is referring to python2 and pip3 is referring to python3. But, when I installed a package via pip3, it showed up in python3.6 but I get an error of "no module named" while I wanted to import it in python3.7.

So my question is, should/can I uninstall python3.6 ? (I would appreciate if someone also provides me an easy way to uninstall python3.6 completely)

What should be my keyword to call python 3.7 from terminal?

What should be my keyword to use pip to install packages onto python 3.7 from terminal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DKBose my question is not about removing 2.7 it is about removing 3.6

Comment: 18.10 is no longer supported. You should use 19.10 or 18.04.

Comment: What would expect to gain from "removing `python3.6`"? Other than disk space, I guess.

Comment: Learn enough about Unix/Linux to run and understand  commands like `type -a python;ls -l /usr/bin/python*;dpkg -l python*`. Hint: Read `man bash` (for `type`), `man ls;man dpkg`

Comment: @waltinator my only aim was not to confuse myself with different versions of python and also with different versions of pip along with them.

Answer (score 1):

**

### Ubuntu version is 18.10

**

**So my question is, should/can I uninstall python3.6 ? (I would appreciate if someone also provides me an easy way to uninstall python3.6 completely)**

No, Ubuntu requires python 3.6 to function.(Since 18.04) If you do so you won't be able to log in after a restart.

**What should be my keyword to call python 3.7 from terminal?**

Configure Python 3 to use Python 3.7:

> - sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6
> - sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7
> - sudo update-alternatives --config python3
> - Choose your preferred python version(for example 2)

Test the Python 3 version

> - python3 -V

**What should be my keyword to use pip to install packages onto python 3.7 from terminal?**

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install
```

Thanks in advance.

### **No Problem!!**

Comment: Thanks! I could not understand exactly the sentence with "(for example 2)" in it. Also I guess, after changing default python version to python3, pip directly refers to pip3

Comment: True but i was answering every question separately. Option 2 is if you have multiple alternatives installed then you can choose Option 0 for python 2.7 Option 1 for python 3.6 Option 2 for python 3.7  In answering to pip, is if you use both python versions.